# Ninject 4.0.0-beta-0134 throws 'A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services'

Tags: c#, ninject

Today I updated our Ninject dependency from 3.3.4 to 4.0.0-beta-0134, but now it throws a circular dependency exception in decorator pattern:

`Unhandled Exception: Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating Program+IService using conditional binding from Program+IService to Program+Service
A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.

Activation path:
2) Injection of dependency Program+IService into parameter service of constructor of type Program+ServiceDecorator

1. Request for Program+IService

Suggestions:

1. Ensure that you have not declared a dependency for Program+IService on any implementations of the service.
2. Consider combining the services into a single one to remove the cycle.
3. Use property injection instead of constructor injection, and implement IInitializable
   if you need initialization logic to be run after property values have been injected.
   `

Here is sample code:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(); 
        kernel.Load(new IocConfig());
        kernel.Get<IService>().Serve();
    }

    internal interface IService
    {
        void Serve();            
    }

    public class Service : IService
    {
        public void Serve() { }
    }

    public class ServiceDecorator : IService
    {
        private readonly IService _service;

        public ServiceDecorator(IService service) => _service = service;

        public void Serve() => _service.Serve();
    }

    public class IocConfig : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IService>().To<Service>().WhenInjectedInto<ServiceDecorator>().InSingletonScope();
            Bind<IService>().To<ServiceDecorator>().InSingletonScope();
        }
    }
```

It seams like it does not like the use of `WhenInjectedInto` in the NinjectModule. I found other similar questions, but none where `WhenInjectedInto` was not working.

One way to fix this is to change the service parameter type from `IService` to `Service` but that destroys much of the reason for using the Decorator.

Do any of you know of another solution/workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making another pass, it would appear that the issue is actually caused by the use of `.WhenInjectedInto<ServiceDecorator>` since there is no differentiation between the bindings.

An alternative is to simply use `Bind<IService>().To<Service>().InSingletonScope();` and then add a `BindingConfiguration.Condition` to your decorator to handle the `Get<ServiceDecorator>()` use case:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Load(new IocConfig());
    kernel.Get<IService>().Serve();
    kernel.Get<ServiceDecorator>().Serve();
}

public interface IService
{
    void Serve();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void Serve() { Console.WriteLine("service"); }
}

public class ServiceDecorator : IService
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public ServiceDecorator(IService service) => _service = service;

    public void Serve() { Console.WriteLine("decorator"); _service.Serve(); }
}

public class IocConfig : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IService>().To<Service>().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IService>().To<ServiceDecorator>().InSingletonScope().BindingConfiguration.Condition =
            (Ninject.Activation.IRequest request) =>
                request.Service == typeof(ServiceDecorator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David! This is exactly what I am looking for! Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear how you're intending to use the decorator from this example, but one possibility would be to apply a new interface to the decorator that in turn inherits from `IService`.

```
public interface IServiceDecorator : IService { }

public interface IService
{
    void Serve();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void Serve() { }
}

public class ServiceDecorator : IServiceDecorator
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public ServiceDecorator(IService service) => _service = service;

    public void Serve() => _service.Serve();
}

public class IocConfig : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IService>().To<Service>().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IService>().To<Service>().WhenInjectedInto<ServiceDecorator>().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IServiceDecorator>().To<ServiceDecorator>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, that would make a lot of boilerplate interfaces that would be very nice to avoid though... Thanks for your input!